# Transferring 2 files simultaneously through a single socket?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sockets

If I want to transfer 2 files at the same time through a TCP socket (to a single client) is it possible to do so through a single socket or do I need 2 sockets to do so?
I do not want file#2 to wait for file#1 to transfer before being transferred. I want them to transfer at the same time.

If I need 2 sockets, what would be the best way to do it? I don't suppose it's possible to just copy the socket and transfer through that as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but queuing theory tells us that transferring one first followed by the other is better according to most speed metrics.  And also needs less logic.

So why do you need to transfer them in parallel?  Are the files growing during the transfer, or some other reason that you can't finish transferring one first?

Comment: Well the thing is:
If I send a file of a couple of MB and afterwards send a file of only a few bytes, the file of a few bytes would not be received before the big file was received.
Also; some of the packets merely contain a command while others contain entire files. I don't want the packets containing a command to wait until the files has been received.

Comment: Yes, mean time to complete smaller tasks is one of the metrics where sequential processing hurts.  You're better off pausing the longer transfer and sending the short file, instead of interleaving, however.

Comment: Perhaps I should just open more socket connections through the same port. That would work wouldn't it?

Comment: @user1876706: Yes that should.